# Ember.js setting the for attribute on label

Tags: ember.js

I have HTMLBars template that has label and a Ember input component, I would like to know what is the best way to set the for attribute on the label reference the component. Is there way I can access the component id from outside the component. I know you can set the manually set the id on component however I would like evade doing that in case this cause duplicate id conflict

Answer (score 1):

I personally set the id on the `input` manually to the result of a concatenation of the input field and the current component id.

so in my `my-form.hbs` i do this:

```
<label for=(concat elementId '-username')>Username</label>
{{input id=(concat elementId '-username') value=username}}

<label for=(concat elementId '-password')>Username</label>
{{input id=(concat elementId '-password') value=username}}
```

This is simple and efficient. It will guarantee a uniq id because `elementId` is uniq. Maybe you could also write a component to wrap this:

*input-with-label/component.js*

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: '',
  inputId: Ember.computed({
    get() {
      return Ember.guidFor(this)+'-inpudid';
    }
  })
});
```

*input-with-label/template.hbs*

```
<label for=inputId>{{label}}</label>
{{input id=inputId value=value placeholder=label}}
```

And then use it:

```
{{input-with-label value=username label="Username"}}
{{input-with-label value=password label="Password"}}
```

Comment: Do you know is there any side effect of this solution?

Comment: Is there a way to get a unique id from just a template on route instead put everything in components?

Comment: @jpoiri You could reopen `Ember.Controller` in an initializer and add an `uniqId` property where you call `Ember.guidFor(this)`. @ykaragol I don't thinks there is any.